# Sending SOAP multiparam message to a Webservice vía Camel routing, with user&pass authentication

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-camel

I've been trying to connect to an external endpoint vía camel routing, with SOAP.

So far I succeded in routing files in my localhost but I cant find how to do this part.

I need to route a message to a webservice in Camel. It needs to authenticate with username and password.

The message requires two parameters as seen here:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <cli:sendOrder>
         <Param1>?</Param1>
         <Param2>?</Param2>
      </cli:sendOrder>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Perhaps you can enlighten me in configuring the endpoint with the two parameters and sending it with a username and password.

Comment: That seems like custom authentication by specifying username and password inside the SOAP message itself. Just set the message body in the Camel message to be the XML with those username and password included.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the camel-cxf endpoint, you can configure the username and password for the basic authentication on the httpconduit just like this.

```
<conduit name="{http://example.com/}HelloWorldServicePort.http-conduit"
  xmlns:sec="http://cxf.apache.org/configuration/security"
  xmlns="http://cxf.apache.org/transports/http/configuration">
  <authorization>
     <sec:UserName>myuser</sec:UserName>
     <sec:Password>mypasswd</sec:Password>
     <sec:AuthorizationType>Basic</sec:AuthorizationType>
  </authorization>
</conduit>
```